# [mini]conda env list is showing environments from a different installation of conda

Tags: python, conda

Multiple conda installations exist on my machine. I have set the `$PATH` to the second one installed under `/Users/steve/conda-hac`

```
(base) 11:16:51/hercules-airflow3 $which conda
/Users/steve/conda-hac/bin/conda
```

Let's create an environment there:

```
$ conda create -n hac_conda
```

However when invoking `conda env list` we see the environments previously created by the original / first `conda` installation:

```
(base) 11:17:14/hercules-airflow3 $conda env list
# conda environments:
#
                         /Users/steve/conda-hac
                         /Users/steve/conda-hac/envs/hac_tests
base                  *  /Users/steve/opt/miniconda3
air37                    /Users/steve/opt/miniconda3/envs/air37
airflow3                 /Users/steve/opt/miniconda3/envs/airflow3
hercl                    /Users/steve/opt/miniconda3/envs/hercl
juventas36               /Users/steve/opt/miniconda3/envs/juventas36
```

I checked to see if the new environment `hac_tests` were in the expected place - and yes it is:

```
3 $ls -lrta  /Users/steve/conda-hac/envs
total 0
-rw-r--r--   1 steve  staff    0 May  1 09:23 .conda_envs_dir_test
drwxr-xr-x   4 steve  staff  128 May  1 09:41 .
drwxr-xr-x  16 steve  staff  512 May  1 09:41 ..
drwxr-xr-x   8 steve  staff  256 May  1 09:41 hac_tests
```

Looking further, after doing `conda init bash`, the conda is still the *other* one.

Notice the `conda` we're executing (`which conda`) is `/Users/steve/conda-hac/bin/conda` but the `conda` returned from `conda init bash` is

```
no change     /Users/steve/opt/miniconda3/condabin/conda`
```

```
$which conda
/Users/steve/conda-hac/bin/conda
(base) 11:48:15/hercules-airflow3 $conda init bash
no change     /Users/steve/opt/miniconda3/condabin/conda
no change     /Users/steve/opt/miniconda3/bin/conda
no change     /Users/steve/opt/miniconda3/bin/conda-env
no change     /Users/steve/opt/miniconda3/bin/activate
no change     /Users/steve/opt/miniconda3/bin/deactivate
no change     /Users/steve/opt/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
no change     /Users/steve/opt/miniconda3/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
no change     /Users/steve/opt/miniconda3/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1
no change     /Users/steve/opt/miniconda3/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1
no change     /Users/steve/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xontrib/conda.xsh
no change     /Users/steve/opt/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh
no change     /Users/steve/.bash_profile
```

So there is strange behavior on the `conda init`. How can I get the environment working properly for the second `conda` installation under `/Users/steve/hac-conda` ?

Comment: "*Multiple conda installations exist on my machine*" Why? What led to having a second installation to begin with? From my perspective, that only creates unnecessary complications with no additional benefits.

Comment: I  use miniconda extensively for various projects.  The new installation is for verifying the automated installation of `miniconda` for use on other machines *that lack conda* . These two installations - local/my machine and verification-of-installation-for-other-machines shall not be mixed .  In fact the second one is repeatedly torn down as part of developing the verification process.  Even without this justification the question can be raised to better understand how `conda` is handling the bash environment.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend test installing directly in a personal user account. Instead, consider testing in a container or on something like GitHub Actions runners.

Comment: Oh actually after seeing your answer then it becomes more clear why testing on a system with multiple conda installations is suboptimal (all env's across all installations going to one file). The conda folks apparently were not expecting this scenario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly coming from the `~/.conda/environments.txt` file. Any time an environment gets activated, it is logged here. Since this is at the user-level, any installation will have access to it.

Comment: oh i see! this appears to be one part of the surprise. The other is that the name does not show up for the new ones . only the directory

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be due to the `conda_init(): it is hardcoded to a particular installation.  Notice the` /Users/steve/opt/miniconda3/bin/conda` within the code:

```
conda_init() {
    # >>> conda initialize >>>
    # !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
    __conda_setup="$('/Users/steve/opt/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        eval "$__conda_setup"
    else
        if [ -f "/Users/steve/opt/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
                 . "/Users/steve/opt/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"  # commented out by conda initialize
        fi
    fi
        export PATH="/Users/steve/opt/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"  # commented out by conda initialize
    unset __conda_setup
    # <<< conda initialize <<<
}
```

I will be creating a second version of the function `conda_hac_init()` that references the new installation under `/Users/steve/conda_hac`